# Problems (cannot) installing/uninstalling Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to update a new version of the TensorFlow but first I want to remove the oldest version by doing the following command:

```
 pip uninstall tensorflow
```

But I receive the following message:

> Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.

But When I run the following command to check if there is any version install:

```
> py -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

I receive the following message:

```
1.13.1
```

The message is wrong or the tensorflow was not successfully installed? How can I upgrade my tensorflow version?

**Note:** My python version is 3.7.3

Thank you!

Comment: try `py -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__file__)`

Comment: Aren't `py` and `pip` referring  to distinct site paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible situation where it can happen is when pip is from one installation of python and your `py` is pointing to different installation of python.

Check if you have multiple python installations ?

```
which pip
which py
```

Make sure both are pointing to same installation

Comment: Yes, is because of that, because if I do `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` I receive a different message. How I uninstall a oldest python instalation?

Comment: @RicardoRocha lets say your `py` points to `/home/abc/anaconda35/bin/python` the you can uninstall tf in that installation using `/home/abc/anaconda35/bin/pip uninstall tensorflow`

Comment: I'm using windows, which command does not exists (I think) and that folder I cannot finde :\

Comment: try `where py` and `where pip`